# What's that washing machine noise and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine, noise

I have a Siemens IQ 300 front loader washing machine (Germany). During a wash cycle, it will at some point make this noise:

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/MgMKZOEHhR0

It mostly seems to make this noise in the second half of the wash cycle.

I already checked the lint filter (where I removed a hair pin, but the noise continued). I also opened up the front and removed the heating element to check for objects but didn't find any.

Is there something else I can check?

Cheers

Comment: The audio is not clear enough to indicate any abnormal noise. It's possible something, e.g., a piece of wire, has gotten stuck in the pump that moves out waste water, but impossible to tell from that clip. Check the shop manual  to see how much trouble it would be to disassemble the machine to get to that pump.

Comment: Does it make noise when draining and not spinning? If you move the drum by hand do you hear any noise?

It would hurt to check the trap in the drain pump. It's designed to be cleaned out periodically. You will have to take the front of the machine off. Look up your model number and you'll probably find a youtube video on how to do that. I've found coins and screws in mine. Certainly sounds like something came out of someone's pocket and is rattling around.